# Differentiate this trigonometric function

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

Let $h$ be defined as

$$h(x) = \begin{cases}\sin(x^2)\cos\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) \quad& x \neq 0\\ 0\quad&x=0\end{cases}$$

The question is:

Prove that $h$ is differentiable at $0$ and find $h'(0)$.

I showed that the left and right limits exist and equal to each other. I also showed that the function $h$ is continuous at $x=0$ but I could not show the right and left derivatives at $x=0$ are equal.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know the product rule for differentiation?

Answer (score 0):

when $x>0, 0< |f(x)| < x^2$

The function is continous at $0,$ and $f(0) = 0$

The right-hand derivative of $f(0)$

$|f'(0)| = \lim_\limits{h\to 0^+}  |\frac {f(h)- 0}{h}| < |h|$

And the left-hand derivative is 0.

As the function is continuous, and the left-hand limit equals the right-hand limit, the function is differentiable and the derivative is 0.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, I knew what I meant to say, but didn't say it.

Comment: Such short-circuits of thought happen to all of us, but it's better  to fix  them, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine the limit of $\dfrac{h(x)}x$ when $x\to 0$.

Now, using equivalence of functions, we get
$$\:\dfrac{h(x)}x\sim_0\dfrac{x^2}x\cos\dfrac1x=x\cos \dfrac1x=O(x),$$
so $\;\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{h(x)}x =0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your work showing that $h$ is continuous at $0$ is correct.  A plot might reinforce your result.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In fact, $\pm x^2$ is an envelope for this $h$.  (Although I make no representation that this is easy to show.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But what about $h'(x)$?  Except at $x = 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
h'(x) &= \left( \cos(x^2) \cdot (2x) \right) \cos(1/x) \\
&\quad{}+ \sin(x^2) \left( \sin(1/x) \cdot (x^{-2}) \right)  
\end{align*}
And a plot of that might help you see why you are having trouble with the limits from the left and right -- neither limit exists.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So how do we show this?  Let $x_k = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k}$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}_{>0}$.  This is a sequence that approaches $0$.  Then $h'(x_k) = \frac{1}{4}(\pi + 4\pi k)^2 \sin\left( \frac{4}{(\pi + 4 \pi k)^2}\right)$, a sequence that approaches $1$.  Now let $y_k = \frac{1}{\frac{-\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k}$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}_{>0}$.  This is a sequence that approaches $0$.  Then $h'(y_k) = \frac{-1}{4}(\pi^2 - 4\pi k)^2 \sin\left( \frac{4}{(\pi - 4 \pi k)^2}\right)$, a sequence that approaches $-1$.  So some care is required to show that $h$ is differentiable at $0$.

As long as $x \neq 0$,
$$  \frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x} = \frac{\cos(1/x) \sin(x^2)}{x}  \text{.}  $$
We have $-1 \leq \cos(1/x) \leq 1$, so
$$  \frac{-\sin(x^2)}{x} \leq \frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x} \leq \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}  \text{.}  $$
Then, taking the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ and applying L'Hopital's rule on the left and right ends of the inequality,
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -2x \cos(x^2) \leq h'(0) \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  2x \cos(x^2)  \text{.}  $$
Now $\cos(x^2) \in [-1,1]$, so as before the expressions on the left and right are bounded by $-2x$ and $2x$.  In the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$, the squeeze theorem forces
$$  0 \leq h'(0) \leq 0  \text{,}  $$
so $h'(0) = 0$.